# React remove multiple items

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of items that can be removed by pressing a button, like shown in the attached screenshot.
[image]

Removing any of the items works fine at the first time, but then when I try to remove another item it won't work because the component receives the data from the previously removed item.

This is my code:
Parent component

```
onDeleteClick(config, e) {
  // it removes the item at the first time
  // on the second try the received config parameter is the same as before
  this.props.deleteConfigAction(config.configId)
  .then(res => {
    ...
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
}

<Flexbox  marginTop='20px' flexDirection='column'>
  {this.state.configurations.map((config, index) => {
    let boundDeleteClick = this.onDeleteClick.bind(this, config);
    return (
      <ConfigCardView
        key={`item-${index}`}
        handleRemove={boundDeleteClick}/>
    )
  })}
</Flexbox>
```

`ConfigCardView` Component:

```
...
<button onClick={(e, config) => this.props.handleRemove()}>Delete</button>
...
```

I can't figure out what I'm missing...

---

UPDATE
I've fixed by updating the `configurations` state property after removing an item:

```
  this.props.deleteConfigAction(config.configId)
  .then(res => {
    ...
    this.setState({configurations: newData})
  })
```

Comment: I found the issue ... I didn't update the `configurations` from state after removing an item. I'm leaving this open because someone may use this code structure to achieve the same goal...